# paginationl seial number in next page in angular?

Tags: angular

In my table, I have the serial number from 1 to 10 and when I move to second-page again it shows the page number from 1 to 10. But it should show 11 to 20 for the second page. How to add my serial number like that?

My code is,

```
columns: [
    {
        field: '',
        title: 'S.No',
        template: function(row, index, datatable) {
            return index + 1;
        },
    },
    {
        field: 'first_name',
        title: 'First Name',
    },
    {
        field: 'last_name',
        title: 'Last Name',
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide your code for the paginator

Comment: `return (currentPage * 10) + index + 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Before the second page, there was only one page. This (first) page had 10 items, so the second page starts at one later.

With ten items per page, the last item of the second page will be 10 greater than the last item on the previous page.

```
First (2nd):  11 = (10) + 1
Last (2nd):   20 = (10) + 10
```

---

Before the third page, there were two pages. Each page has 10 items, so the third page starts after two times 20 items.

```
First (3rd):  21 = (10 + 10) + 1
Last (3rd):   30 = (10 + 10) + 10
```

---

Before the `n`th page, there were `(n-1)` pages. Each page has 10 items, so the `n`th page starts after two times `(n-1) * 10` items.

```
First (nth):  (n - 1) * 10 + 1
Last (nth):   (n - 1) * 10 + 10
```

---

So, instead of doing `index + 1`, you need to do `(pageNumber - 1) * numberOfItemsPerPage + index + 1` in order to get the correct number.

Answer (score -1):

You may use it like this:

```
{{ (config.currentPage - 1) * config.itemsPerPage + i +1 }}
```

Comment: Please add information to the answer itself instead of relying on an external link.